Is it possible to become a good physicist through self study
Is it possible to do self research in physics, in a sense that one can come on par with knowledge/understanding of doctrate and post doctrate students in the subject so that he could be capable of publishing his own findings and theories, while doing a 9 to 6 job? This may sound very weird but when a person, who loves exploring nature through physics, had to take a job due to his family/economic reasons sees his dream breaking apart he can't help but think about giving a last try. As this matter is very important and may influence a life changing decision,only fact based answers may be appropriate. Motivation quotes and examples of ultra rare people who may have managed to accomplice this feat may be misguiding. Take into account that i have a bachelor degree in physics and maths and a very average brain that unreasonably loves physic Thanks

Gaining the "knowledge/understanding of doctrate and post doctrate students" is literally a 9 to 5 job at least and often more. Are you willing to have a second 9 to 5 job next to the one you already have?

Please note that you should try to avoid paying for your own PhD. That said, most PhD positions are paid positions, they just tend to pay less, often much less, than entry level industry positions. So while saving sounds like a good step, saying that you should aim to save enough to support yourself for 5 years without working is a bit extreme. PhD bursaries usually support "student style" living -- so you might want to save to make up the difference and keep your living standard, or even just reduce your outgoings by as much as you can; but probably not to cover everything

In short: no. On average and on median, it is non-sense to study physics as a side-thing.
Said this, if you really have to fullfill your deeper ego in discussing physics at the highest possible level, you need some rigid effort.
You just need to save money to support yourself for living 5 years without working. So you would better spend your current free time using your average knowledge of statistics to get relatively rich at playing poker, to collect a little sum for your own use.
When you collcted this little sum worth 5 years of life without working, you can enroll in a MSc in physics and afterwards try to get a paid PhD position. If you do not manage to get a PhD position, you can always use your own funds and pursue a self-funded PhD.
Please note: it is not possible to get to that point not only in physics, but in many if not all branches of knowledge ...

While a blunt answer to your question is simply no, there are non-traditional models of pursuing a doctoral degree (part time and partially funded) that can be combined with a part-time job or other obligations.
I can't speak for other regions, but in mainland Europe, many Master's degree programs can be studied part-time (and are free or cheap, tuition-wise). If you don't intend to pursue a full-time research career, doing a career-accompanying Masters degree might give you insight into research physics while still having some income.

As someone who studies mathematics as a hobby in their free time and just published their first paper last year I would like to offer my perspective.  I do not know much about physics, but if you are interested in theoretical physics then I would assume the situation is somewhat similar to mathematics.
It is unlikely that you will be able to contribute to physics to the same degree as a practicing physicist.  That being said, I think it is still possible to contribute in a meaningful and fulfilling way.
In mathematics, there are opportunities for contributing to the field outside of publishing a cutting-edge result.  For instance, this could mean publishing an interesting, but relatively minor result, or a new proof of a known result.  In addition, there are a number of journals with problem sections that one can submit their own problems to or solutions to other people's problems.
I do not know if similar opportunities exist in physics but I wanted to point out that, if you love physics there may be ways to contribute in your free time while working your 9 to 6 job.
